# Power BI - get selected value from slicer to use it on line chart's x axis

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Im trying to get a value from the Slicer that I selected to use on the Line chart's x axis. But it doesnt work. I've created a column with a parameter to add those values to Slicer.

[Image of column to add those values to slicer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7c0D.png)

[Image of Slicer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD56z.png)

What im doing here is getting the weight from the table for example 2224 and divide it with selected value of Slicer and subrtact the decimals from that result by using INT() and than multiply it with the result.

This is the column that i use for run my function here
[Image of Column code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss11D.png)

This is the measure one
[Image of Measure code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x04nc.png)

And the problem is if i want to use Column, the value doesn't get transferred to the table.
but if i want to use the Measure it transfers but i cant put it on the X Axis. The column can't get the value in real-time to the table.

I've searched for the Column one and i found this information:
[Image of information about Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzBCM.png)

The image of multiple tables that i want to transfer data in:
[Image of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZfQw.png)

So what can i do about it to transfer data to table?

I've tried to search about what i wanna try and found a way to fix it.